# How to communicate between different networks?

Tags: networking

I have two PCs, as depicted in the figure.

Because of practical constraints, I cannot change anything on PC2, i.e., I cannot change its IP address and gateway (blank).

On both PCs, the subnet mask is '''255.255.255.0'''.

On PC1, I can only configure the gateway IP address.

Ideally, I would like both PCs to "think" they were communicating in the same network range (no gateways needed as far as the PCs were concerned).

Would this be feasible?

If yes, what kind of functionalities those routers must implement?

[image]

Ideally I want to be able from PC1 to

`ping 192.168.1.11`

and get responses from `192.168.2.11`, i.e., the router(s) would handle all the address translation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change PCs, it needs to be done on gateway.

Try changing the network mask from `255.255.255.0` to `255.255.0.0` (or from 24 to 16) on the routers (LAN interface).

If possible you could also change the network mask on PC.

Comment: Thank you. But, that would imply changing the net mask on PC2 as well, which I can't. I added an ping example in my post.

Comment: Try changing only the routers network mask. This way, from PC1 you can ping 192.168.2.11 directly. Otherwise Router2 will need an Subnet1 IP, firewall and route rules.

Comment: Thank you @Eduardo. But not being able to change the net mask on PC2, PC2 will "only see" requests from the 192.168.2.x range. I added the net masks to the post for clarification. The only thing that crossed my mind was "playing" with the routers and their configuration... some kind of address translation.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the fact that the Router2 isn't the gateway for PC2 and also PC2 has no gateway.